# Why is the Click Event not triggering jQuery Slide Down?

Tags: jquery, html

I have coded the following jQuery, that should make a `div#show` slide down when the link is clicked. When tested, nothing seems to happen. Any help with errors is appreciated.

http://jsbin.com/exakuj

**HTML**

```
<header>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
</header>
<section>
  <a href='#' id='click'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit vestibulum convallis.</a>
  <div id='show'></div>
</section>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#click').click(function() {
$('#show').slideDown('slow', function() {
// Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

First there's nothing in the #show tag for it to slide down. Put some content in it. Second, you must call this onReady of your document - this ensures the tags you are referring to are loaded and present when the script executes

```
$(function(){
  $('#click').click(function() {
  $('#show').slideDown('slow', function() {
  // Animation complete.
    });
  });
});
```

EDIT: See here - http://jsbin.com/exakuj/5/edit

Comment: Being a little picky, ```$(function(){})``` actually fires on onReady event, when the DOM has been parsed. onLoad fires after all the external resources have been loaded too.

Comment: @SusanRobinson, see http://jsbin.com/exakuj/5/edit. You should hide the #show first

Comment: @Arun The code you suggested seems to be working now, Is it possible when clicked again it slides back up?

Comment: Yes you can, instead of .slideDown, use .slideToggle